# Taxonomy field deployment problem

Tags: taxonomy

I have encountered the following problem...
I was trying to create an SPField of 'TaxonomyFieldType' type. So that I created it's xml definition (including the hidden note field) in a farm solution, but any attempt to deploy the project ends up with a feature activation error (where I'm mapping this field with the corresponding term set) saying that field with such GUID (I mean my taxonomy field GUID) is not found on the site.

Field XML definition:

```
<Field ID="{C6721D87-1561-443C-A0C6-9A9447F363B2}"
  Name="SoftwareStatus"
  DisplayName="$Resources:ENRCSoftware, SoftwareStatus;"
  Required="FALSE"
  Type="TaxonomyFieldType"
  ShowField="Term1033"
  EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
  Group="$Resources:ENRCEntity, FieldsGroup;"
  StaticName="SoftwareStatus"
  AllowDeletion="FALSE"
  DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
  Indexed="FALSE"
  Sealed="FALSE">
<Customization>
  <ArrayOfProperty>
    <Property>
      <Name>TextField</Name>
      <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      p4:type="q6:string"
      xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{47524C37-C325-4846-B7AF-FE66BDC693BC}</Value>
    </Property>
  </ArrayOfProperty>
</Customization>
</Field>

<Field ID="{47524C37-C325-4846-B7AF-FE66BDC693BC}"
    Name="SoftwareStatusTaxHTField0"
    DisplayName="$Resources:ENRCSoftware, SoftwareStatus_0;"
    Hidden="TRUE"
    Type="Note"
    Group="$Resources:ENRCEntity, FieldsGroup;"
    ShowInViewForms="FALSE"
    StaticName="SoftwareStatusTaxHTField0"
    CanToggleHidden="TRUE"/>
```

In a FeatureActivated event of a feature `web.Fields.Contains(new Guid("{C6721D87-1561-443C-A0C6-9A9447F363B2}"))` returns false.